# PowerShell script to archive all old files in a directory based of month

Tags: powershell

Using PowerShell I got a requirement to archive all historical files from the past 7 years to be zipped based on month and Year of creation date and delete files after zipping.

After implementing the solution I should see the files as shown below
Example:

```
FolderName_2013-Jan.zip
FOlderName_2013-Feb.zip
FOlderName_2013-Mar.zip
FOlderName_2013-Jan.zip
FOlderName_2017-Jan.zip
FOlderName_2017-Dec.zip
```

I have found several articles but they are lacking the information to Dynamically pass each month Month Start and Month End (Ex: 2013-01-01 to 2013-01-31 or 2015-06-01 to 2015-06-30)to filter files for all months from the year 2013.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try anything so far? Follow the steps below...

- Get the unique create dates using `Get-ChildItem` with `Select-Object -Unique`
- Get all the files and store them in a variable
- `ForEach` date filter the files using `Where-Object` and pipe them to `Compress-Archive`

Try it at your level best and still not able to figure it out then refer to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/kpatnayakuni/f969b234ae6cf729c3d2d7c8d283c350)

Comment: Thank you Kiran
Will try making use of your suggestion.

Comment: I have to create these zip files in same folder where these individual files are residing by looping through all sub folders in archive directory. Hoping I have to perform nested for each.

Comment: Did you refer this [gist](https://gist.github.com/kpatnayakuni/f969b234ae6cf729c3d2d7c8d283c350)?

Comment: Hi Kiran
I did look at the code but the code is not zipping all the files due to the way CreationTime was used in the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
function Compress-Files {
[CmdletBinding()]
[Alias()]
[OutputType([int])]
Param
(
    # Sourcepath
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true, Position = 0)]
    $SourcePath,

    # number of months to compress in past
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true, Position = 2)]
    $Months

)

#region variables
$FullPath = $SourcePath + '*.*'
<#
    $date = (get-date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    $yesterday = (get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyyMMdd")
    $lastmonth = (get-date).AddMonths(-1).ToString("yyyyMMdd")
    $lastyear = (get-date).AddYears(-1).ToString("yyyyMMdd")
#>
#endregion


#region Compress months
#Compress files based on months in the past.
$Months = '-' + $Months
$Month = (get-date).AddMonths($Month).ToString("yyyyMMdd")

#$files = Get-ChildItem $FullPath | ? {$_.CreationTime -ge $Months -and $_.CreationTime -le $lastmonth}
#$files = Get-ChildItem $FullPath | ? {$_.CreationTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd") -ge $Months -and $_.CreationTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd") -le $lastmonth}

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $FullPath | ? { $_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd") -le $Month -and $_.Name -notlike "*.zip" -and $_.Mode -notlike "d*" }



foreach ($file in $files) {
    $filename = ($file.LastWriteTime).ToString("yyyy-MM")
    $DestinationPath = $SourcePath + $filename + '.zip'
    $file | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath $DestinationPath -update  
    Remove-Item $file -Force
    #if ($delete){ }


    ###Move Archiving logs to a text file
    "$DestinationPath|$file " | Out-File  "C:\temp\ExtractsArchive\Archivelog.txt" -Append
}
#>
```

}

```
#####Finally use the function on each and every sub directory
```

$RootFileDirectory = "C:\temp\ExtractsArchive\"

$Directories = Get-ChildItem -Path  $RootFileDirectory -Recurse -Directory | Select FullName

ForEach ($Directory IN $Directories) {

```
$SourcePath = $Directory.FullName.ToString() + "\"

#$SourcePath.GetType()

Compress-Files -SourcePath  $SourcePath -Months 2
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Get-ChildItem` command as suggested by Kiran above, you can generate FileInfo and DirectoryInfo objects.  Each of these have the timestamp for the file and/or directory stored in various properties, such as `LastWriteTime`, `LastAccessTime`, `CreationTime`.  Each of these properties contains data of type `[DateTime]`.  Once you have a `[DateTime]` item for each of your files/folders, you can do something like this:

```
#Set variable $MY to be 7 years ago
$Now = (Get-Date)
$MY = $Now.AddYears(-7)

#Write custom Get-ChildItem statements to put list of files/folders in $AllItems variable

#Now, loop through with each month/year
Do
    #Filter $AllItems for the proper Month-Year
    $ThisMonthsItems = $AllItems.Where({$_.LastWriteTime.Month -eq $MY.Month -and $_.LastWriteTime.Year -eq $MY.Year})

    #Use $ThisMonthsItems to add items to your .zip file
    #This step left for you to fill with your compression routines

    $MY = $MY.AddMonths(1)
Loop Until ($MY.Month -eq $Now.Month -and $MY.Year -eq $Now.Year)
```

You will likely need to adjust the loop to get the right time window, but the basic idea should be there for you.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I use the following script to both remove old files and zip files older than a given date.

In my case, I want to remove **and** archive files older than 3 months.

I run this once a month, at the start of the month and keeping only the last 3 months set of files. Come next month, the oldest month's worth of files are dropped off.

Note, in my script I am deleting old `*.gz` files, but compressing (archiving) old `XML` files.

```
$datestamp = (Get-Date).toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")

$server = "\\myserveraddress\"

$Path1 = $server + "c$\filelocation\files"

$Monthsback = -3    #keep 3 month's worth of files only, but check every month (so 1 month will drop off!)
$CurrentDate = Get-Date
$DatetoDelete = $CurrentDate.Date.AddMonths($Monthsback).ToString("yyyyMMdd")

try {
    write-host "$datestamp [info] Started"
    write-host "$datestamp [info] Cut off date: " $DatetoDelete

    #delete old files
    write-host "$datestamp [info] Removing files ..."
    Get-ChildItem $Path1 *.gz | Where-Object{ $_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd") -lt $DatetoDelete } | Remove-Item

    # delete any previous copies of tmp.zip
    if (Test-Path ".\tmp.zip") { Remove-Item ".\tmp.zip" }

    # file all files and compress them into tmp.zip
    write-host "$datestamp [info] Compress and archive all old XML files ..."
    Get-ChildItem -Path $Path1 *.xml | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd") -lt $DatetoDelete } | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath .\tmp.zip

    # if zip created...
    if (Test-Path ".\tmp.zip") { 
        write-host "$datestamp [info] Rename ZIP archive file ..."
        $filePath = ".\tmp.zip";
        $directory = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($filePath);
        $strippedFileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($filePath);
        $extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($filePath);
        $newFileName = [DateTime]::Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm") + "_XMLfiles" + $extension;
        $newFilePath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($directory, $newFileName);
        Move-Item -LiteralPath $filePath -Destination $newFilePath;
        
        write-host "$datestamp [info] Remove old XML files ..."
        Get-ChildItem $Path1 *.xml | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd") -lt $DatetoDelete } | Remove-Item
    }
}

catch {
    $message = $_
    Write-Warning "$datestamp [error] $message"
}

finally {
    write-host "$datestamp [info] FINISHED"
}
```